# String dimension error whel dealing with new operator

Tags: c++, c, string

I'm trying to make something similar to the strlen(str,str) function (I have a return string) to learn using pointers and the new operator, here is my code:

```
char* strcat(char str1[], char str2[]){
int len=strlen(str1)+strlen(str2);
char* sfin = new char[len];
int i=0;

for (i=0;i<strlen(str1);i++)
    *(sfin+i)=*(str1+i);    //this could be *(sfin+i)= str1[i]

for (int j=0;j<strlen(str2);j++)
    *(sfin+j+i)=*(str2+j);  //this could be *(sfin+i+j)= str2[j]

return sfin;
```

}

It works, except for the thing that the new operator allocates too much memory (or is it right?), as seen from variables watcher:

[image: variables]

[image: console]

P.S. in the main() function I retrieve str1 and str2 using gets(char*) and put them using puts(char*). `len` has the right content (9).

Results can be various: sometimes it puts the correct string and sometimes only two "strange" characters, depending on parametres.

Comment: If you're using C++, why don't you just use `std::string` and not have to worry about memory management?

Comment: To start with, it looks like you haven't put in the null character (`'\0'`) :-)

Comment: @AdamRosenfield
I didn't know about that, this is homework and I have a low knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null-terminated strings need to be, well, null-terminted. You only copy all the characters up to the null-terminator but not the null-terminator itself. That is, if a program looks at the content of you string, it will continue looking until it finds a null-terminator. Make sure you add a null-terminator and also make sure the memory is deleted, e.g., using

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> strcat(char const* str1, char const* str2) {
    // ...
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[len]);
    // ...
    return ptr;
}
```

BTW, your use of `strlen()` in each iteration of the loop is likely to result in rather bad performance, especially if you have long strings.

Comment: yes, i had to change the loop.
fixed using:
    'for (int j=0;j<=strlen(str2);j++)
  *(sfin+j+i)=*(str2+j);'  

because i had to copy the '\0'

Answer (score 1):

In c and c++, strings have to be null terminated. The resulting string contains the values of string1 and string2 but it is not null terminated. The resulting string's length should be equal to strlen(strin1)+strlen(string2)+1 and the plus 1 char can be assigned the null terminator '\0'